# Osascript "text returned of" input does not include whitespace

Tags: bash, macos, shell, applescript, osascript

I have the following script for creating a new user on macOS:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

consoleUser() {
    echo "show State:/Users/ConsoleUser" | scutil | awk '/Name :/ && ! /loginwindow/ { print $3 }'
}

displayfortext() { # $1: message $2: default text
    message=${1:-"Message"}
    defaultvalue=${2:-"default value"}
    user=$(consoleUser)
    if [[ $user != "" ]]; then
        uid=$(id -u "$user")

        launchctl asuser $uid /usr/bin/osascript <<-EndOfScript
            text returned of ¬
                (display dialog "$message" ¬
                    default answer "$defaultvalue" ¬
                    buttons {"OK"} ¬
                    default button "OK")
            EndOfScript
    else
        exit 1
    fi
}
realname=$(displayfortext "Enter the real Name (e.g. John Doe)" "John Doe")
username=$(displayfortext "Enter the Username (e.g. john.doe)" "john.doe")
sudo dscl . -create /Users/$username RealName $realname #Set Real Name (e.g. John Doe)
```

Now after the last sudo command (and a few others I left out) the user is successfully created. The problem is, that **the users name (John Doe) is only "John" and everything behind the whitespace disappeared.**

Does someone have an idea how to fix this? I do not want another character between John and Doe (nothing like John_Doe) **it has to be a whitespace** (company policy).

Comment: In your dscl command, you are using bash variables `username` and `realname`, but I don't see where they are assigned a value.

Comment: I added the username line - realname declaration was in there already (2nd and 3rd line from bottom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash breaks the arguments on white space. Hence, if `realname` contains a white space, the individual words in it become two different parameters. Quote the parameter as `"$realname"` to avoid this.

Comment: I did change `realname=$(displayfortext "Enter the real Name (e.g. John Doe)" "John Doe")` to `$"realname"=$(displayfortext "Enter the real Name (e.g. John Doe)" "John Doe")`. Now there's no name at all after creating the user.

Comment: This change does not make sense!!! As I said, the problem is in **passing the parameter**, so you have to quote it of course in your `dscl` command, not at the place where you assign the variable,  and the quoting is not `$"realname"`, but `"$realname"`!

Comment: @LWun  : You can read [here](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html) about quoting in bash.